# ¿como actualizar datos usando onfocus en grails?

Tags: javascript, html5, grails, groovy

Estoy trabajando en Grails 3.8, tengo un input Telefono en una vista, con el valor que tiene en la base de datos, lo que quiero es que con el evento onfocus ese dato se actualice por otro que ingrese el input esta de la siguiente manera:

```
 <input name="telefono" type="text" class="form-control" value="${profesor?.telefono}" onfocus="actualizar(this.profesor.telefono)"/ >
```

la función es esta:

```
function actualizar(telefono, id) {
console.log(telefono)
console.log(id)
    var a= $.ajax({
    type:'post', 
    url:CONTEXT_ROOT+'/profesor/actualizar/'
    data: "id"+id+'?telefono='+telefono,
    success:function(data,textStatus) {
    }});}
```

mi controlador recibe la funcion asi:

```
def actualizar(){
    def profesor = Profesor.findAll(params.id)

    def telActualilzar = params.telefono

    profesor.telefono=telActualilzar
    profesor.save(flush:true, failOnError:true)
    render 'ok'

 }
```

cuando pongo el cursor en el input me sale este error

> node to traverse cannot be null!. Stacktrace follows:
>
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null

y no actualiza los datos, alguien?

Answer (score 0):

La manera correcta de obtener un elemento por medio de su 'id' es usando el método `get()`.

De esta forma:

```
def profesor = Profesor.get(params.id)
```

Lo que estás haciendo es usar `findAll`, no apto para tu escenario, ya que este método sirve para hacer una consulta que te podría devolver uno o varios elementos, y tú solamente vas por uno. Además, al utilizar `findAll` debes poner el criterio por el cual deseas consultar (que es por lo que te sale el error).

Por ejemplo:

```
def alumnos = Alumno.findAllByGrado(params.grado)
```

Más info sobre 'Dynamic Finders' en Grails: http://gorm.grails.org/latest/hibernate/manual/index.html#finders